# How to append a variable to an existing array in php

Tags: php, arrays, url

I need to append a variable to an array . 
Please guide me if i go wrong in any line :

`$arr= array();` // defines arr an empty array ?

`$deposit=$_POST['amountdeposit'];` // this is a variable i want to append to arr array.

// now array arr looks more a like to `array("$deposit ")` ?

and then i need to pass this array in a url .

When again there's a value in `$_POST['amountdeposit']` it is again appended to this existing array.

Comment: [array_merge](http://be2.php.net/array_merge)

Comment: You can append a value to an array with `$array[] = $value;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be like with using `[]`:

```
$arr   = array();
$arr[] = $_POST['amountdeposit'];
```

#### Output

```
array (size=n)
  0 => int 10
  1 => int 20
  2 => int 30
  n+ => ...
```

Comment: The thing is $deposit = 10; on pass 1, it should be stored in array arr, now when next time the $deposit=20, it should be like 0=>10 1=>20 ?? getting it ??

Comment: This is just sample. So you should use only `$arr[] = $_POST['amountdeposit'];`

Comment: Oka. Now i need to send this $arr in a url '$url="deposit.php?arr[]=$arr";' is it fine ? GET this url on that page and again send it back to this page where i will be using $_POST['amountdeposit'] 

How will be the previous value be appended to this new one ?? or it will work the same way ??

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION` keep array data. If you want to pass with url. You should `[http_build_query](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)` function.

Comment: Thanks i will check on that :) @Bora

Answer (score 1):

i guess you want this

```
$arr[] = $_POST['amountdeposit'];
```